# Xcode - control drag function not working

Tags: xcode, iboutlet

Beneath is my code, 
Currently, it isn't working and allowing me to connect a button to my swift file (main storyboard). Also, the timer function isn't working, would this be to do with the function not working as well?

unsure on how to fix this, let me know if you need any other screen shots.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var CounterLabel: UILabel!
var time = 30

   var timer = Timer()
   @IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton)
   {
       timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

   }
   func action()
{
       time += 1

   }

    //GIFS
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.  
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```